# knockout.js getCartParam method

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, subtotal

Currently, in my minicart.phtml override file I have knockout.js code like this to display the number of items in my cart:

```
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
```

If an item is added to my cart I also want to display the current cart subtotal. Is there a method for directly displaying this with knockout.js or is there another simpler way to achieve this? How do I find out what other things I can display with knockout.js?

Answer (score 2):

You can display subtotal using this code.

`<!-- ko text: getCartParam('subtotalAmount') --><!-- /ko -->`